# Right way to allocate and release memory for array of objects that I will use in a std::map

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I have a collection of polygons that I retrieve from the database and which I wish to store in a binary tree for fast accessing. As a binary tree I use std::map.

I created this solution, which is outlined below, but I think that it is not correct because I do not call free() to release the memory allocated by malloc().

### My questions (problems):

1. Is it correct to use std::map if I only need to insert and access elements of this map? I just want to find geometries fast by their ID's.
2. In the std::map I store pointers to the geometries instead of storing geometries themselves. Is this a good idea? Before I tried to store the geometries themselves, but then I realized that the std::map makes a copy of the object, which created problems.
3. In the method ConvertSpatial2GPC(..) I create gpc_geometry objects, which create references, which I release at gpc_free_polygon(..). But I can't release the gpc_geometry object itself, because I do not have a reference to it at that point.

### I use the following structures:

```
typedef struct                      /* Polygon vertex structure          */
{
  double              x;            /* Vertex x component                */
  double              y;            /* vertex y component                */
} gpc_vertex;

typedef struct                      /* Vertex list structure             */
{
  int                 num_vertices; /* Number of vertices in list        */
  gpc_vertex         *vertex;       /* Vertex array pointer              */
} gpc_vertex_list;

typedef struct                      /* Polygon set structure             */
{
  int                 num_contours; /* Number of contours in polygon     */
  int                *hole;         /* Hole / external contour flags     */
  gpc_vertex_list    *contour;      /* Contour array pointer             */
} gpc_polygon;

typedef std::map<long, gpc_polygon*> layer;
```

### My workflow is as follows:

1. Load items from database
2. Call method initializeLayer() which returns a layer (see previous typedef)
3. ... Work with the layer ...
4. Call method freeLayer() to free the memory used by the layer

### Code for initializing geometry objects:

```
layer initializeLayer() {
    //... database connection code

    //find the count of objects in database
    int count = ...

    //helper object for loading from database
    spatial_obj* sp_obj = NULL;

    //initialize a array to hold the objects
    gpc_polygon* gpc_objects;
    gpc_objects = (gpc_polygon*)malloc(sizeof(gpc_polygon) * count);

    layer myLayer;

    int i = 0;

    //... query database
    while(db.Fetch()) {
        id = db.GetLongData(0);
        db.GetSDO_Object(&sp_obj); //load from database
        db.ConvertSpatial2GPC(sp_obj, &gpc_mullad[i]); //convert polygon to GPC format
        //insert a pair (ID->pointer to the geometry)
        myLayer.insert(layer::value_type(id, &gpc_objects[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return layer;
}
```

### Code for freeing layer:

```
void freeLayer(layer myLayer) {
    for (layer::iterator it = myLayer.begin(); it != myLayer.end(); ++it) {
        gpc_free_polygon(it->second); //frees the memory from this geometry object
    }
}
```

### Code for freeing geometry object:

```
void gpc_free_polygon(gpc_polygon *p)
{
    int c;

    for (c= 0; c < p->num_contours; c++) {
        FREE(p->contour[c].vertex);

    FREE(p->hole);
    FREE(p->contour);
    p->num_contours= 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for clear explanations and good formating. If only all questions could be like that.

Comment: This is not C. It seems more like a C++. As such there is no reason why you should create list by hand with `malloc`. Look for `std::vector`.

Comment: @user694733, maybe You could add Your comment as an answer, so we can discuss it. I understand that if I would use a vector in the method initializeLayer(), then at the end of this method the vector would be destroyed and the memory would be freed. But that would invalidate the pointers in the std::map myLayer, which I want to use outside of that method. Or should I create the vector object outside of the method initializeLayer() and pass it as a parameter to the method inititalizeLauer(), so it would be freed only at the end of the work?

Comment: @Rauni Well, the big picture of your design is a bit fuzzy, but I would say, yes. Passing vector to initialization function is probably what you want. Also, you return entire myLayer map from init function. You probably want pass that also from outside and fill in function. In general, prefer collections first, then references, then pointers with `new/delete` and finally, use pointers with `malloc/free` only if you have to.

Comment: @user694733 I think that I can entirely drop the std::map, because I really don't need it (see the answer that I posted). I think that I should just use a vector of structs, where each struct consists of an ID and a gpc_polygon. This vector would be sorted by the ID. At the end of program, I would iterate over the vector and free all of the gpc_polygons. But would I need to free the memory allocated for structs also, or does std::vector take care of that automatically?

Comment: @Rauni If you store objects (instead of pointers to objects) in vector, then vector will destroy objects when vector itself is destroyed. That's why I said to prefer collections over raw allocations; it makes memory management easier.

Comment: @user694733 I added the code I ended up with in my answer, if You are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I am making things more complicated that they should be.

I don't really need a std::map to store the pointers. I can instead ask the polygons from the database so that they they are already ordered by their ID's. And then I can store the polygons in a static structure (array or vector). When I need to find a element by its ID, I will just use a binary search algorithm to find it (which is logarithmic time like the search algorithm used by the binary tree, anyway).

So, my method initializeLayer() will return an array or vector instead, which I will free at the end of the program.

EDIT: I found that I don't have to implement the binary search myself. There is a class for this: std::binary_search. Link: [Binary search algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/)

EDIT2: So, that is what I ended up with:

### Object structure

```
typedef struct {
    long id;
    gpc_polygon gpc_obj;
} object;
```

### Layer structure

```
typedef std::vector<muld*> layer;
```

### Code for initializing geometry objects:

```
layer initializeLayer() {
    //... database connection code

    //find the count of objects in database
    int count = ...

    //helper object for loading from database
    spatial_obj* sp_obj = NULL;
    object* object_ptr = NULL;

    layer myLayer;
    myLayer.reserve(count);

    int i = 0;

    //... query database
    while(db.Fetch()) {
        id = db.GetLongData(0);
        db.GetSDO_Object(&sp_obj); //load from database

        object_ptr = new object;
        object_ptr->id = id;
        db.ConvertSpatial2GPC(sp_obj, &object_ptr->gpc_obj);
        myLayer.push_back(object_ptr);
        i++;
    }

    return layer;
}
```

### Code for freeing layer:

```
void freeLayer(layer myLayer) {
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != myLayer.size(); i++) {
        gpc_free_polygon(&myLayer[i]->gpc_obj);
        delete myLayer[i];
    }
}
```

### Code for doing binary search:

I found out that the std::binary_search only returns whether it found or did not find the object. std::lower_bound() to the rescue!

```
//Create empty object for searching
object* searched_obj = new obj;
object* found_obj = NULL;
searched_obj->id = id;
layer::iterator it;
it = std::lower_bound(myLayer.begin(), myLayer.end(), searched_obj, obj_comparer);
if(it != kiht.end()) {
    found_obj = *it;

    if(found_obj->id != id) {
        //Error!
    }
} else {
    //Error!
}
//Release memory
delete searched_obj;
```

### Function for comparing objects

```
bool obj_comparer(object *a, object  *b) {
    return a->id < b->id;
}
```